# Amplify functions deployment not working for Golang runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, lambda, aws-amplify

I'm quite new to the Amplify function world. I've been struggling to deploy my Golang function, connected to a DynamoDB stream. Even though I am able to run my lambda successfully by manually uploading a .zip I created myself after I built the binary using `GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build src/index.go` (I develop on a mac), when I use the Amplify CLI tools I am not able to deploy my function.

This is the folder structure of my function `myfunction`

```
+ myfunction
├── amplify.state
├── custom-policies.json
├── dist
│   └── latest-build.zip
├── function-parameters.json
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── parameters.json
├── src
│   ├── event.json
│   └── index.go
└── tinkusercreate-cloudformation-template.json
```

The problem is I can't use the `amplify function build` command, since looks like it creates a **.zip** file with my source file `index.go` in there (not the binary), so the lambda, regardless of the `handler` I set, it seems not able to run it from that source. I record errors like

- *fork/exec /var/task/index.go: exec format error: PathError null* or
- *fork/exec /var/task/index: no such file or directory: PathError null*

depending on the handler I set.

Is there a way to make Amplify build function work for a Golang lambda? I would like to successfully execute the command `amplify function build myfunction` so that I will be able to deliver the working deployment by `amplify push` to my target environment.